# Superscript inside subscript in math mode

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

When a superscript is placed inside a subscript, its relative position to the "base" becomes different, as shown by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\inset{L^-}

\begin{document}

\[
\inset \text{ vs. } \int_{l \in \inset}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to define the macro so that it looks the same in subscripts?

Comment: In the latter case, the symbol occurs in "cramped" scriptscript style; in the former, it occurs in non-cramped script style. The solution consists of forcing non-cramped script style for the latter case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the superscript-`-` symbol is in "cramped scriptscriptstyle" in the second example, but in (non-cramped) scriptstyle in the first. To change the second case to the non-cramped style, add a `\scriptstyle` directive ahead of `l\in\inset`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\inset{L^{-}}
\begin{document}
\[
\inset \text{ vs.\ } \int_{\scriptstyle l\in\inset}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use `\vphantom{x}` as a virtual subscript for `L` and you are good.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\inset{L^-}
\newcommand\insetv{L_{\vphantom{x}}^{-}}


\begin{document}

\[
\inset \text{ vs. } \int_{l \in \insetv}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: not quite the same.  the insertion of the `\phantom` causes the superscript to shift ever so slightly to the right.  try placing the phantom subscript *after* the superscript.